# javafx setting up a linechart

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I am trying to set up a linechart in a scene and have it like this so far-

```
<LineChart fx:id="historicalReportGraph" label="Purity History Graph"       GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                                  <xAxis><CategoryAxis label="Month" lowerBound="0" upperBound="11" tickUnit="1"/></xAxis>
                                  <yAxis><NumberAxis label="PPM" lowerBound="0" upperBound="100" tickUnit="1"/></yAxis>
                                </LineChart>
```

because I dont know how to set up a categoryaxis properly in the scene...

how do I set up this category x axis so that it is by month, the 12 months of the year, january thru december?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are setting up the scene in FXML?

The simplest answer is to set the xAxis to NumberAxis as this is the definition of what values it is displaying. and change the yAxis to CategoryAxis (unless you wish it to be a number as well then you would set it to NumberAxis as well)

Comment: what I want is to know how I set up the category axis i have no idea what terms to use i just know it doesnt use upperBounds and lowerBounds... I want the x Axis to be a category axis I just dont know how to set it up so its a category axis with 12 categories  (strings) january - december... and the y axis is going to be numbers for each month...

Comment: ahh rightyo, you cannot set those values in the FXML, those have to be defined in your controller class. using the fx:id in your controller class by using @FXML LineChart historicalReportGraph; as your variable you can use the example in http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm to help'

Comment: i know how to do that part what i dont know is what to put for the x axis part in the scene part- do i just put

Comment: <xAxis><CategoryAxis/></xAxis>

Comment: Yup, that's all there is to it :)